# I have dual boot enabled in my laptop. None of them is booting now

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Lenovo laptop. I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16 installed. One day after I updated my Windows, my windows wouldn’t boot as it stayed on a black screen forever after the Lenovo logo flashed. Then I forcefully powered it off and then booted Ubuntu which worked well for 2-3 days and now even Ubuntu isn’t booting. I tried to restore my laptop using OneKey recovery (Lenovo) but the process freezes at initialisation state. How can I recover my laptop? And yeah, my hard drive is working fine.

Comment: Without more details, it's unclear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Updating Windows can cause issues with dual booting machine.  However, this usually results in Windows overwriting the boot sector and just removing the ability to access Linux.  It is strange that after the Windows update, that Windows is not bootable and Linux worked.  It is even stranger that Linux eventually stopped working.  Those points, coupled with the fact that the Lenovo restore is failing, my gut feeling is your hard drive is corrupted or failing.

If your data is valuable to you, I would back it up immediately.  Since you are running Linux, a Windows recovery DVD/USB wont be able to read to Linux partitions.  However, Linux can read both OS file systems.  I would boot off a Linux live USB/DVD and backup your data.  Alternatively, you could remove the hard drive and hook it up to another computer to copy the data.  While booted to a Live distro, you should run a SMART test on the drive, to see if it is reporting failures.